# Alert on Specific Text Entered In Input Field

Tags: javascript, php

I have two Log In script on my webpage. One For Paid Members And One For Free Members

Username during registrations are provided by serverside with use of mysql Id...e.g. "evachan2014001" for paid members and "evachanfree001" for free members. Both mysql Databases are different for free and paid members.

Can I Alert (Like - This LogIn Form Is For Paid Members...etc...) if Any user enters a word "free" (i.e. exists in username "evachanfree001") in Paid Members Log In Form - username input field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call an `onblur` event for textbox (which calls a function when the focus from the textbox is changed) like:

```
<input name="username" id="username" onblur="check()">
```

and write corresponding javascript function like this

```
<script>
function check()
{
  var name=document.getElementById('username').value;
  if(name.indexOf('free') > -1)    //  returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs
  {
   alert("This LogIn Form Is For Paid Members.");
   return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: he wants to know if the text CONTAINS the text and not if it is equal to the text.

Comment: It's also bad practice to rely on evaluation of a JS string for handlers by putting them in as element attributes. You should rely instead on using `addEventListener` on the element in JS.

Comment: thank you for help. as username is provided by phpcode..it is unique like "evachanfree(some number)"...so your code worked perfectly for me...if any user uses other text, it already shows "invalid username/password" warning...so i need only to check if username contains word "free" or not...so thank you once again...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var value = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
if( value.indexOf('mytext')>=0)   //checks for mytext to be present anywhere in the string
    alert('you've entered mytext');
else
    //anything you want to do
```

you will need to have mytext as the id for that input element and can use any of the JS Events to trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can use a simple `stripos()` and JS alert to achieve this..

After you get the values from the `<form>` and when the user presses login button..

**`Login.php`** [Warning : This is just an illustration code , as you haven't posted anything ]

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
    if(stripos($_POST['username'],'free')!==false)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('You are not a paid user');</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        //Allow Login...
    }
}
```

Comment: Bad for the network. You can do that using javascript on the page itself instead of submitting the form.

Comment: @Ritikesh, You need to learn. You should not rely on client - validation first as they(values you enter in the form) can be easily faked or tampered.

Comment: It is just an alert message to the user while he enters text in the fields. I'm obviously aware of javscript issues. But this would be bad for performance. And he is going to validate everything on the server side only on submit. Not on single text inputs.

Comment: `And he is going to validate everything on the server side only on submit. Not on single text inputs` AFAIK , there will be just two fields on login. The username and the password...!

Comment: yeah of course. But If you see the answer he selected, I think all he wanted to do was alert users if they entered 'sometext' in their userids. That isn't something too important to be tampered with right? So IMHO, it is better of to be done on the client side itself. The answer you posted was for the server side login validation. But that wasn't what he was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a example how you do it. The code should be placed after your input field.

```
var freeUsername = document.getElementById("field name");
var regularUsername = document.getElementById("field name");
regularUsername.onchange = function() {
  if(/free/i.test(regularUsername.value)) {
    alert("This LogIn Form Is For Paid Members");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `keyup` event on the field and then check if it contains the string `free`. That might cause some trouble though because the user could be called something like `freeman2014` or `freemanfree2014`, where only the last one is a free user.

In this case, you could try to use a regular expression to match the rule
'some text - followed by `free` - followed by digits - followed by the end of the string'.

[Here's a good reference for RegExp in JS.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)